# How to get the index of each pane in a window with synchronized panes?

Tags: ssh, tmux

Suppose the following scenario. I have machines named `host1` through `host4` to which I want to connect in one pane each.

I have split my Tmux window evenly into four panes so each of them can host an SSH connection to those hosts.

All is fine when already connected and having the panes synchronized. I can issue commands which get executed on all of the hosts simultaneously.

However, now I was thinking that it would be quite nice to be able to connect to each host by issuing the *exact same command*. This way I could enable synchronization between panes even before connecting to those hosts.

Alas, I am unable to come up with a method that works. What I tried was this:

```
ssh root@host$(tmux run "echo '#{pane_index}'")
```

The idea here being that this should resolve to `ssh root@host1` through `ssh root@host4` depending on the pane in which the command gets to run.

Unfortunately the result was rather unexpected. Even though the command executed (while the pane 1 was active), the connections were all established to `host1`. So evidently that variable `pane_index` refers to the currently active pane rather than the pane in which the command is being issued.

How can I achieve connecting to `host1` through `host4` making use of the pane index (or something else) by issuing the *exact same command* in each pane, rather than having to type individual commands?

NB: all indexes start at 1, but of course this could be made to work even if that weren't the case, e.g. by means of `$((...))` in Bash.

Answer (score 0):

There are few issues.

1. For `$(foo)` to work `foo` should print the desired information to its stdout. `tmux run …` does not do this; it *displays* the result in copy mode. You want `tmux display -p …`.
2. `tmux display -p '#{pane_index}'` can give you useful numbers when you invoke the command pane by pane, but in synchronized panes the output will be identical. This is because if you don't specify a pane (with `-t`) then the currently active pane is assumed. When you invoke pane by pane, each time the proper pane is active. When you invoke in synchronized panes, exactly one pane is active and its index will be returned by all commands.
3. To reliably identify the pane a command runs in, use the `$TMUX_PANE` environment variable. In your case you can't do this directly.

   ```
   # flawed
   ssh root@host"${TMUX_PANE#%}"
   ```

   The problem is `$TMUX_PANE` corresponds to `#{pane_id}`, not to `#{pane_index}`. Pane IDs are unique across the entire tmux server. You will get `%0`, `%1`, `%2`, `%3` for the first four panes created. The panes in question may as well give you `%7`, `%8`, `%13`, `%14`, if other panes were created earlier and in the meantime.

   The right way is to use `$TMUX_PANE` to specify a pane and `#{pane_index}` to retrieve the desired number.

Solution:

```
ssh root@host"$(tmux display -p -t "$TMUX_PANE" '#{pane_index}')"
```

It generates `host0`..`host3` but it looks like you know what to do to get `host1`..`host4`. I decided not to obfuscate the solution with `$((…))`.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the variable `$TMUX_PANE` that tmux places in the environment of each pane's command. For example if you give the command

```
tmux send-keys  'echo host${TMUX_PANE#%}' Enter
```

you will see in each pane `host0`, or `host1`, and so on. So replace echo by your ssh command.

Comment: -1. The variable is not useful by itself in this case. See my answer for explanation.